# Replace in C# and replaceAll in Java

Tags: c#, regex

Is `Replace` in C# the same as `replaceAll` in Java?

I'm trying to replace anything in parenthesis but it doesn't seem to work in C#. I need the output to be just "blah".

```
string username = "blah (blabla)";
userName = userName.Replace("\\([^\\(]*\\)", "");
```

It works when I use it [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html).

Comment: string.Replace does not use regex, just plain strings.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are looking for the [`Regex.Replace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx) method:

```
string username = "blah (blabla)";
Regex rgx = new Regex("\\([^\\(]*\\"));
userName = rgx.Replace(input, "");
```

The `string.Replace()` method handles just that, *string* replacements - it does not cover regular expression.

Answer (score 4):

You are currently doing a basic string replace.

If you want to use regular expression, use:

```
username = Regex.Replace(username, "\\([^\\(]*\\)", "");
```