# How to remove initials from name using C#

Tags: c#, regex, validation

I need to remove initials from a name, like,

**K A M Paul Silvester** - > Expected output:  **Paul Silvester**.

I have found a solution to do it using java, but I need to do it using C#

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String input = "K A M Paul Silvester";
    input = input.replaceAll("\\b[A-Z]+(?:\\.|\\s+|$)", "").trim();
    System.out.println(input);
}
```

I also need to check input name is valid or not, if the user input name with initials method should be returned false, else true. how can I do it

```
public bool checkName(string name)
{

}
```

Comment: Sounds like both C# and Java regexes are not so different, try this one: `input = input.Replace(@"\b[A-Z]+(?:\.|\s+|$)", string.Empty).Trim()`. Also read this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214902/replace-in-c-sharp-and-replaceall-in-java.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto no its not working, its return same input

Comment: This is a tricky one since the number of letters in the initials can be different from name to name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a regex to found what are initials and what is full-name, if so I can suggest you to use a regex like this:

```
var match = Regex.Match(input, @"(?<initials>([A-Z] )+)?(?<name>.+)");
if (match.Success)
{
    var initials = match.Groups["initials"].Value;
    var name = match.Groups["name"].Value;

    var hasNotInitials = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(initials);
}
```

**[C# Demo I](https://rextester.com/HOUK51182)**
**[C# Demo II](https://rextester.com/WFLVB85344)**

Comment: Thank you, when user input equal  `"Paul Silvester";` no name print. I also need method  to verify user input have initials or not how to write such a bool method

Comment: thanks sir, can you please tell me how can I create bool method to accept to user input. I mean if user input is a valid name or not? if user input with initials I need to return false ,else true

Comment: As you want I add a `hasNotInitials` variable and so on ;).

Answer (score 0):

As I already mentioned in the comments, this is a tricky one since the number of letters in the initials can be different from name to name. Here is something you can do that might work most of the time.

**No regex needed.**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String input = "K A M Paul Silvester";
            String[] nameaArr = input.Split(' ');
            String firstName = nameaArr[nameaArr.Length - 2];
            String secondName = nameaArr[nameaArr.Length - 1];

            String name = firstName + " " + secondName;
            Console.WriteLine(name);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I used **C#** here because you tagged **C#** to the question. If you are using **Java**, you can do the same

> **Warning!**
>   The result can be wrong if the user inputs the name with
>   initials after the name. Eg: Paul Silvester K A M

Answer (score 0):

```
(.\b)*(.*) Group 2 will have the rest after the initials.
```

K A M Paul Silvester -->  K A M (Paul Silvester)

K A Paul --> K A (Paul)

Sorry I don't use C# so perhaps you have to use double excapes?